# Postgres install via Octopus error: No mapping between account names and security IDs was done

Tags: postgresql, octopus-deploy, postgresql-11

I am attempting to install postgres sql (v11) via an octopus tentacle but keep running into an error (same on any machine I attempt). Replaced the system name with 'computer' to post.

If I run the same installer by hand its fine and I can also run the installer via powershell using the same script we use in octopus to launch the installer (and with same params) so it's obvious there is something going on between the tentacle service user and how the installer is try to setup something but that's as far as I have been able to take the issue.

From bitrock_installer.log
Executing icacls "C:\Windows\Temp/postgresql_installer_7dae697831" /T /Q /grant "WORKGROUP\computer$:(OI)(CI)F"
Script exit code: 1332

Script output:
 Successfully processed 0 files; Failed processing 1 files

Script stderr:
 WORKGROUP\computer$: No mapping between account names and security IDs was done.

Error running icacls "C:\Windows\Temp/postgresql_installer_7dae697831" /T /Q /grant "WORKGROUP\computer$:(OI)(CI)F": WORKGROUP\computer$: No mapping between account names and security IDs was done.
Error running icacls "C:\Windows\Temp/postgresql_installer_7dae697831" /T /Q /grant "WORKGROUP\computer$:(OI)(CI)F": WORKGROUP\computer$: No mapping between account names and security IDs was done.
Exiting with code 1

Looks like a similar issue in this thread 
[Invoke-AzVMRunCommand and Start-Process under specific user on remote VM using Azure Runbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59226683/invoke-azvmruncommand-and-start-process-under-specific-user-on-remote-vm-using-a)

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue and tried many things...what ended up working for me was changing the computer name to just "computer"...i had unicode emojis in my computer name which is what caused the issue...

Comment: Can confirm this was the cause - I had an emoji as mine too. In later version of Windows 11, they now restrict PC renames to only letters, numbers and hyphens.

Answer (score 0):

i had same issues trying to install postgres. it was because i had emojis as part of my computer name and changing my PC name to only string characters solved the problem.